# Java collection sorting vs custom sorting - speed

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, collections, format

Using java sorters, i.e:

```
Collections.sort(myArrayList, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return x;
        }

    });
```

and

```
myArrayList.sort(new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return x;
        }

    });
```

surrounded with 'out' tags show that the method takes 600-800 milliseconds to complete.

This is just too big of a delay when sorting 50 - 100 arrays.

My questions is, would creating custom methods to sort arrays be any quicker?

The above code works very well, but is just way too slow to implement...

Each array (myArrayList) has about 44 elements.

It takes 600-800 milliseconds to complete 1 sort, therefore 50 - 100 arrays could take up to 80000 milliseconds.

Executable:

```
 System.out(timeMillis);
Collections.sort(fourtyFourItemsArrayL, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                Item i1 = o1 >= 16 ? player.getInventory().getItem(o1 - 16) : player.getEquipment().getItem(o1 - 1);
                Item i2 = o2 >= 16 ? player.getInventory().getItem(o2 - 16) : player.getEquipment().getItem(o2 - 1);
                int price1 = i1 == null ? 0 : i1.getDefinitions().getProtectionPrice();
                int price2 = i2 == null ? 0 : i2.getDefinitions().getProtectionPrice();
                if (price1 > price2)
                    return -1;
                else if (price1 < price2)
                    return 1;
                return 0;
            }

        });
 System.out(timeMillis);
```

Comment: that would depend. Do you need to sort the arrays in and of themselves? or sort the arrays with respect the the elements they have (comparing arrays by some properties of their elements)

Comment: These are not `array`s but `List`s. Do you mean 50-100 Lists or  50-100 elements of a List ? Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: Before diving down this rabbit hole, please make sure you have data to support it. Measuring performance in Java is surprisingly hard. Have a look at http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

Comment: Also, if you just want to sort ints, a good first try could be to use int arrays, as opposed to List<Integer>

Comment: The performance is clearly visible during execution, it is quite slow, also I mean 50-100 LISTS and not ELEMENTS, sorry if the op is confusing. arrays are harder to sort compared to lists

Comment: It might be initially slow, and get quicker due to JVM warmup as well as JIT-compiling. I strongly advise you to read up on Java benchmarking before trying to beat the default sort implementation. Also, about how many elements are in your lists?

Comment: there are about 44 in a single list

Comment: So, sorting 44 elements takes several hundred Millis, or sorting 50-100 lists, each with about 44 elements takes  several hundred Millis? In either case, this seems strange. Could you please update the question with all your code, including how you're measuring the time, so it's easier to help you?

Comment: updated the main question with that extra info

Comment: More of your code is still required. I measured a sort similar to what you're describing, and it took 1 millisecond, even though I didn't take my own advice and run it through a micro benchmark, so in reality it should be significantly quicker on my machine. Show your code and how you're measuring the time it takes. I really think we're missing some critical information here.

Comment: Updated again with the main body and my execution

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, The Java Collections.sort() use sorting algorithm with complexity O(n lg n).

If you want to build your own sorting method that faster than Collections.sort(), you need to use O(n) sorting algorithm like [Radix-Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) or [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

If your constraint only 50-100 elements in array, I prefer to use Collections.sort() rather than write a lot of code for just sorting the numbers. There are not much difference between O(n lg n) vs O(n) when n <= 100.

If you want to sort 50-100 different array, you can utilize [Java Threading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If the implementation of compare is slow, then all sorting will be slow to a greater or lesser degree. First of all, you really should make sure everything required for the sort is available in memory. What does player.getInventory().getItem(...) do? Does it dive into a database? or a file?
If it does, you're in for a bad ride.
Also, consider that each item will be part of a compareTo (much) more than once.
I'd suggest, instead of sorting `List<Integer>`, create `List<Item>` then sort those.
That will dramatically reduce the number of times you're doing `Item i1 = o1 >= 16 ? player.getInventory().getItem(o1 - 16) : player.getEquipment().getItem(o1 - 1);`

Also, if `i1.getDefinitions().getProtectionPrice()` dives into a file, database or similar, you need to pre-fetch that.
You could create a class containing only the Integer, and the protectionPrice, create a list of this class, based on the original list, and then sort that one. I can almost guarantee a speed increase of 100x or so.

In summary, I believe that your problem isn't the sort algorithm itself, but how you've implemented compareTo, and changing sorting algorithm will not solve your problem.

Comment: getInventory and getEquipment are just maps of <int, item> therefore running them shouldn't take much time at all, and getDefinitions, getProectionPrices are just integers in their respective class, though to get rid of them completely i could change fourtyFourItemsArrayL from list<int> to list<int, itemprice> would that increase performance?

Comment: You can, just as a timing test, replace your compare() with `return o1 - o2` just to see how expensive your compare method is in comparison with a trivial one. If you need as quick as possible, I'd go with the last suggestion in my answer, creating a class containing the original Integer, and the price. If you only need quick enough, then you might get away with smaller modifications.

Comment: doing so improved the performance significantly, thanks for the help (implementing a map instead of list)

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please take your time to accept the answer that led to the solution to you question.